# How to have includes / elemnts in Zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, include

I'm new to Zend Framework.

I have a menu of tabs that is used on various views but I need to highlight which section the user is in.

I have seen placeholders but they don't seem very flexible and don't really do the job since I can't access any variables to see what area the user is in.

Normally I would do this as an include, but not sure where to go with Zend.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Zend_Navigation takes care of all your navigation problems:

[Zend Framework: Documentation: Zend_Navigation - Zend Framework Manual](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.html)